# MongoDB findOne not returning anything

Tags: php, mongodb, database

According to the PHP mongo page for findOne, this should be working fine but its not.

```
$email = array('email' => $_POST['email'];
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
$xyz = $conn->database->users;
$cursor = $xyz->findOne($email); 
print_r ($cursor);
```

This is working when using the find method instead of findOne.

```
$email = array('email'=>$_POST['email']);
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $conn = new MongoClient( 'localhost' );
        $db = $conn->database;
        $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'users');
        $cursor = $collection->find($email); 

        foreach ($cursor as $obj){
            $test = $obj['email'];
                    print_r($test); }
```

Can someone explain why this is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findOne() does not return a cursor like find() does - please check the documentation here:

http://www.php.net//manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php

In addition you appear to have a syntax error in your code, you are missing a right parentheses in the first line. Also, using variables named "$cursor" when it's not returning a cursor tends to be a bad idea as it causes confusion for those viewing the code.

Finally, you are using different approaches between your two code samples - different variable names, different strings passed to MongoClient(), one uses a call to MongoCollection() and one does not, etc - very easy for problems to crop up in those differences.

Taking all that into account, I'd propose the following:

```
# Add right ) at end of following statement
$email = array('email' => $_POST['email']);
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
$db = $conn->database;
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'users');
$findoneResult = $collection->findOne($email); 
print_r ($findOneResult);
```