# Mongodb findOne has no result / throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm very new to Node/js/mongo so bear with me if I have this totally wrong.

I have a local db.js file that uses callbacks to give me context on a Mongodb collection object. 
The object is valid and calling find() from my callback returns a cursor to the var cursor as expected. However, the following call to findOne returns null for both err and res.

If I call findOne in a similar manner to find, node throws a TypeError complaining that I haven't passed in a callback to findOne.

```
db.openDB(
function(err, db)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        var cursor = db.find();
        console.log(cursor);

        db.findOne({}, 
        function(err, res)
        {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
});
```

Edit: [db.js](http://pastebin.com/Deh49vVV) for @JohnnyHK
I notice now that I'm opening the collection queue twice but I'm still lost, so have a look.

Comment: You appear to be calling `findOne` on your database object and not a collection.

Comment: No, it's definitely the collection object. I have a callback inside of my db.open to conn.collection('schema', callback) that then returns its contents to the original callback I pass in.

Comment: OK, can you edit your question to show the code for `db` then?

Comment: If you call cursor.each(), is there actually something in the cursor?

Comment: @Imyers it is null. Even after commenting out close(). There is at least one record in this collection.

Comment: Your database is called queue and your collection is also called queue?

Comment: I have no idea, I thought a database was a collection in mongo

Comment: No, the default database is "test"

Comment: [this](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-create-database-or-collection-in-mongodb/) and @Imyers were correct, I was not properly understanding the database to collection relationship, and now my idea is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `cursor.each()` and see if there is actually something in the cursor. Then try commenting out the `conn.close();` in your openDB function. I think you are closing the connection before you get your data.

Also try

```
db = new mongodb.Db('test', server, {w:1}),
```

instead of 'queue' if you are using the default database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to this question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24129547/3993375
`FindOne()` does not return a cursor like `Find()` does.
For example, if you have an empty collection and use `Find()`  you will get a count of 0.
If you tried the same against an empty collection using `FindOne()` you get a null error.